# qlikview stacked bar chart with dates

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

[image][image]

I want to create a stacked bar chart with dates I tried with numbers instead of dates and it is working but with date it is not working

Stacked bar chart in the image below is not showing dates given in table and also not stacked bars

I just replaced numbers with dates and its not working
is it possible to create a stacked bar chart with dates
I am new to qlikview Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why isn't it working? Can you post some screenshots please

Comment: i have added file in the below qlikview forum url https://community.qlik.com/thread/289890

Comment: the provided link to Qlik Community is leading to protected area and cant be open. Please upload screenshot (at least) here if you want to receive an answer. Its not clear at all whats not working and what your goal is

Comment: in the attached image of qlikview stacked bar chart date is not coming its showing some other dates